# Should I put a script in /etc/cron.daily directory when create a cron?

Tags: cron

I found a good manual for [crontab](http://awc.com.my/uploadnew/5ffbd639c5e6eccea359cb1453a02bed_Setting%20Up%20Cron%20Job%20Using%20crontab.pdf)

I'm wondering I should put a script in one of directories as described in the manual or not to make it run.
For example, if I want to create a cron everyday, should I really put a script I want to run everyday in /etc/cron.daily and then create a cron?

Is a cron not working if I just create a crontab like putting script in another directory ( instead of /etc/cron.daily )?

> 00 1 * * *  /home/test/daily.sh

instead of

> 00 1 * * *  /etc/cron.daily/daily.sh

I created a cron a couple of times a long time ago. 
But I don't think I put script in such directories ( ex: /etc/cron.daily ) at that time.

Answer (score 1):

You can place your script that cron should run anywhere you want as long as access rights permit it. Since, as far as I know, `/etc/cron.daily` is run as root it doesn't matter.

I don't know what your script does but as a rule of thumb I wouldn't run scripts with higher privileges than actually needed. Jobs can also be created for a certain user. You can check out `man crontab` on your distribution.